# How can I use an array in blade.page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have an array that I generated in my Controller.php page like this and I want to use it in blade.php page in javascript. I will explain the details below. I'm moving this to my blade.php page using compact('ids') .

```
array:11 [▼
  0 => 100485
  1 => 100496
  2 => 100497
  3 => 100498
  4 => 100499
  5 => 100500
  6 => 100502
  7 => 100504
  8 => 100482
  9 => 100486
  10 => 112995
]
```

Then there is an input like this on my blade.php page.

```
<input type="text" value="{{ request()->get('id') }}" name="id" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="ID" required>
```

There is a form like this.

```
 <form action="" id="your_form" onsubmit="yourFunction()">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input id="coffee-submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-35" type="submit" value="detail">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </form>
```

yourFunction() like this

```
var action_src = "http://localhost:8000/admin/" + document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value + "/orders";
var your_form = document.getElementById("your_form");
your_form.action = action_src;
```

No problems so far and it works. What I want to do is put a control in this function. If the value entered in the input exists in $ids, the function should work. So let me give an example:

```
var ids = <?php echo json_encode($ids); ?>;

if (ids.includes(document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value)) {
var action_src = "http://localhost:8000/admin/" + document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value + "/orders";
    var your_form = document.getElementById("your_form");
    your_form.action = action_src; 
}
```

I tried as above. I tried the following, it didn't work. `var ids = JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($ids) }}');`

Comment: Did you try `var ids = {{{ json_encode($ids, true) }}}` ?

Comment: I've tried but i can not. Successful in example data array like this. var ids =['100485','100'];@ITgoldman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an issue with string to integer comparison. So I added `Number()`

```js
var ids = [12, 13, 14, 15];


if (ids.indexOf(Number(document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value)) > -1) {
  console.log("ok, do the ajax");

} else {
  console.log("not found");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="14" name="id" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="ID" required>
```

Comment: What exactly does -1 mean here?  @ITgoldman

Comment: The `indexOf` the value in the array (or string). It's always an integer. If it's -1 then not found.

Comment: Got it. It's looking at indexes one by one. Like, does it exist in the zeroth index, does it exist in the first index. Good work, thanks again. @ITgoldman